# How to encrypt an email with S/MIME without a file in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, smime

I need to encrypt an email with S/MIME.
I have everything in place (certificates, private keys, openssl_pkcs7_encrypt() etc.).

The problem currently is, that I do NOT want to encrypt a file, since saving a file on a hard drive is an additional security risk. But since openssl_pkcs7_encrypt() only does that, I am a little stuck here.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to encrypt a email string on the fly to S/MIME.
I would take anything from internal PHP functions/methods to external libraries.

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but have you tried to see if that function can use php://memory as the file path?

Comment: I have never used that. do you have a link where I could find some documentation on it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Since "php://memory and php://temp and not reusable, i.e. after the streams have been closed there is no way to refer to them again. " I do not know how that would help me :/

Comment: I cant get it working, it is checking that the path is a file. You may need to use another function in the OpenSSL module to encrypt, then build the message headers separately and combine it all into a valid email header+body.

Comment: There is no other one. ;)

Comment: Well you won't like this suggestion... grab the source, alter the function to use an input string instead of a file, compile. Or write to disk anyway and shred it, like demonstrated in the php doc comments on this function.